# Entity reference to role

Tags: 9, group, entities

I want to add an Entity Reference field to a Group Type entity, referencing User Roles.
When I add a Entity Reference > Other > Roles field, the creation/edition form of this Group Type throws the attached errors:

[image]

Despite they're not usual, does Entity Reference fields to user roles work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in Opigno LMS about configuring entity forms for groups, so the error I reported previously is not related to the reference field.

Just for completion, I reported the bug for OpignoLMS here: https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_lms/issues/3414721

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks bot, I edited it following this recommendation.